# angularfire2 for firestore observable subscribing once at a time

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I want make a firestore get items observable.  But the problem is it subscribes once a time.  Below is my code:

In provider:

```
this.allSponser = this.afs.collection<Sponsoremphasized text('sponsors').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => { 
    return actions.map(a => 
    { 
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Sponsor; 
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id; 
        return data; 
    }); 
}));
```

in signup page:

```
this.allSponser.subscribe(data=>{ console.log(data); })
```

printing for the first time of load if I am goingback to any other page and coming back to again signup it is not printing.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When you post questions, format your code sections using the `{}` icon on top of the editor, and make it easy to read (line breaks, indentation, ...).  Your question, as originally posted, was almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just mentioning when you navigate away from your component it will destroyed and will recreated, so keep that in your mind, you need to subscribe to `observables` in `ngOnInit` and `unsubscribe` in 'ngOnDestroy'

The other point is I usually return the `observalbe` from my service something like this

```
getSoponsors() {
return this.afs.collection<Sponsoremphasizedtext>('sponsors').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => { 
    return actions.map(a => 
    { 
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Sponsor; 
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id; 
        return data; 
    }); 
})); 
}
```

then in my component

```
isAlive: boolean = true

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getSoponsors()
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive))
    .subscribe(data => ...)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.isAlive = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks RezaRahmati for your answer but i don't want to subscribe the function each time i want to store the that observable in a variable and subscribe it.so it will reduce my no call to firebase
Ex-
this.allSponser in this variable i want to store the observable and subscribe it in each page